# Php - retrieve informations from an xml file

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

I'm approaching web programming. I need to retrieve some informations from a web page. I have the url of the page, so I want the html source code, translate it into xml and then use the dom functions of php to fetch the informations I need.

My php code is this:

```
$url=$_POST['url']; //url

$doc_html=new DOMDocument();
$doc_html->loadHTML($url); //html page
$doc_xml=new DOMDocument();
$doc_xml->loadXML($doc_html->saveXML()); //xml converted page

$nome_app=new DOMElement($doc_xml->getElementById('title'));

echo $nome_app->nodeValue;
```

I get this fatal error:

> Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Invalid Character Error' on this line:

```
$nome_app=new DOMElement($doc_xml->getElementById('title'));
```

What's wrong? Is it the entire process html-to-xml? I found some example on the web and should work...
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solved! Simply:

```
$doc_html=new DOMDocument();
$doc_html->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
$doc_html->saveXML();
$nome = $doc_html->getElementsByTagName('h1');
foreach ($nome as $n) { 
   echo $n->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Maybe the code was too messy before.
Thanks everybody for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define XML entities for the special characters that you're using in your HTML.
It must be the same kind of problem than here: [DOMDocument::loadXML vs. HTML Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262051/domdocumentloadxml-vs-html-entities)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a preg_match() solution to get the content you need over parsing the whole document as XML. Specially if the document becomes invalid for some reason you won't get your info anymore.

Comment: You, and @Bgi, are right, but this is my situation: I have a huge source code and I don't know the DTD's that an XML file need. Parsing and correcting the whole document it's gonna be useless because I only need some html content, and a way to retrieve these without parsing a very long string, hence the use of DOM.

Answer (score 0):

best way is to use xpath queries,

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

it is very fast

Comment: Was my second thought, but I prefer to use DOM because the source is very long and mazy, so I'm better using the tag names :)